# Turing machine that accepts L = {a^nb^2n : n ≥ 0}

Tags: turing-machines

write a Turing machine that accepts L = {a^nb^2n:n ≥ 0} where there are double the amount of b's in comparisons to the amount of a's. So aabbbb would be accepted but aabbaabb would not. I am unsure of how to check that there are twice as many b's then a's. So far i have a change it to an A move to state 1. Then check if a, move to right stay in the same state, if empty go to the reject state, if b change to B move to the right and the next state.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Answer (score 2):

For this general kind of language, the usual technique is to simulate what you'd do with a pencil and paper: make multiple passes along the tape, "crossing out" an $a$ and two $b$'s on each pass. When you run out of stuff to cross out, accept or reject as appropriate.

Comment: so for each a that is crossed out two bs would have to be changed.

Comment: @Suppa_REDH Exactly.

Comment: i think I've come to an answer I've tried two simple tapes and it seem to work, i was just wondering does the state have to end up at the start to be accepted?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the state [ending] up at the start."

Comment: I should have worded it better, i meant does the position at which you enter the accept state have to be the same position you started from, e.g. q1aabbbb qaccAABB

Comment: No, you can enter the accept/reject state whenever you want.